# Confused with inherited functions

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Fixed: modified as such:

```
3rd code piece, 1st line:    
static void writeFile(User &user)
```

User class:

```
User class:
void print() made public
```

Now it works as intended. Thanks to everyone that helped.

This is the original post:

```
1. class User {
2. protected:
3.      string name;
4.      string surname;
5.  .
6.  .
7.  .
8.      void print() {
9.          cout << name << " " <<surname; //etc
10.     }
11. }
```

Inherited class:

```
1. class DiscountUser : public User {
2. public:
3.      void print() {
4.          cout << "Discount ";
5.          User::print();
6.      }
7. }
```

And later in another class I have:

```
1. void writeFile(User user) {
2.     user.print();
3. }
```

And in another one:

```
1.  User *user = NULL;
2.
3.  if (userType == "Discount") {
4.      user = new DiscountUser(name, surname, code);
5.  }
6.  else {
7.      user = new BonusUser(name, surname, code);
8.  }
9.  writeFile(*user);
```

I get an  error C2248: 'User::print' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'User'.

I know I get it because it's trying to access print() in the parent class. Is it because of the first line of the third code piece or did I really mess up with the pointers in the fourth one? Or because I'm a total loser and I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: my c++ is a bit rusty,  but since `User.print` is protected,  I would expect the `User.print` to be accessible from the `DiscountUser` class but not from "another class", which is one of the places where you're calling it from

Comment: for the sake of experimentation, what happens when you change `void writeFile(User user) {` to `void writeFile(DiscountUser user) {`

Comment: Since you went into the trouble of adding line numbers, why don't you tell us precisely on which line you get that error message?

Comment: @MikeNakis 3rd code piece, 2nd line.

Comment: @SamIam If i change it to DiscountUser user it works fine. But the thing is I want to access it from BonusUser as well. I know I'm missing something pretty basic.

Comment: Missing something pretty basic? All you are missing is a `public:` in the 1st piece of code, line 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the issues discussed in the other answers, you haven't used the `virtual` keyword on `User::print`. That means that even if everything were public, calls to it from a `User*` variable would always call the base method, even if the variable contains a derived object.

Looking back at the original question, I wonder if perhaps what you mean to do is have a public pure virtual `print` method in `User` and a protected non-virtual `printImpl` method that gets called from `DiscountUser::print`.

Comment: Virtual keyword "fixed" the error. I will never want call User::print. Only DiscountUser::print, and whatever::print

Comment: In that case, my suggestion of a pure virtual User::print is probably what you want.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler knows which access rules apply by looking at the type of the pointer. Because the pointer is a `User *`, and `print` is protected in that class, it won't let you access it.

As a general rule you should keep the access level the same between the base and derived classes.

In addition to the compile error, you also have an error because `writeFile` is taking the object by value instead of by reference. When the parameter is copied for the function call, you'll get "slicing" where the type of the object is converted back down to the base class.

Comment: I told you two things: first make `print` a public function in `User`, second change the parameter to `writeFile` from `User` to `const User &`.

Comment: I tried it, and i also modified Class::print to     virtual void print() const
however it still doesn't work as intended although I got rid of the compiler errors

Answer (score 1):

In C++, access is determined by a variable's static type, not dynamic. Since `writeFile`'s parameter's static type is `User`, `print` is `protected`, now matter what the dynamic type of `user` may happen to be.

Also, you should definitely pass `User` objects by reference (or pointer), not value. Otherwise you get what is known as "slicing" where only the base part of an object is copied, and that will really give you headaches.